# How to set a transparent image as a background?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to display a fullscreen transparent image anytime there is an active menu button in cocos2d. How do I do that?

Comment: can you give more details on what you mean please?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to provide a popup dialog underlay, you can use CCLayerColor:

```
CCLayerColor* underlay = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 127)];

[self addChild:underlay z:(something less than your button's z)];
```

If it has to be a specific image, initialize the image and do the second line above using your CCSprite.